# О происхождении слов "предварительный" и "проворный"

Tags: этимология

На сайте **ответов mail.ru** можно прочитать:

**Предварительный** — префиксальное производное от древнерусского глагола "варити (варяти) " — упреждать, опережать, предостерегать. 
Тот же корень в другой огласовке находим в слове ***проворный***. https://otvet.mail.ru/question/35740222

**Связь этих слов показалась мне сомнительной.**

У Шанского слово ***предварять*** имеет таких исторических родственников, как ***варежка, варяг***. У Крылова ***проворный*** предположительно связан со словом ***вор***. У Черных эти слова не рассматриваются.

**Насколько достоверны  исторические связи приведенных слов?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В старославянском (и в древнерусском) языке был глагол *варити* (*варѧти*), от которого с помощью приставки *прѣд-* образовался другой глагол *прѣдъварити* (*прѣдъварѣти*). Это всё точно.

Если у Шанского так написано («имеет таких исторических родственников, как варежка, варяг»), то он не прав. (Но я больше верю, что вы неправильно его истолковали. В моем издании словаря Н. М. такой ерунды не пишет.) *Варяг* и *варити* — очевидные разнокоренные формы, с совершенно разной историей. Другое дело, что есть две версии происхождения слова ***варежка***, согласно одной из которых, оно — родственник *варяга*, а согласно другой, — родственник *варити*.

Что же касается *проворный* и *варити*... это тоже сомнительно, о чем сообщается, например, в РЭС А. Е. Аникина: «Родственные образования иногда усматривают
в *провóрный*, (?) *вор*, но отношения не вполне ясны. По семантике и строению рус. *предварúть* сходно с франц. *prévenir* ‘предупреждать’ (Mach.: 677)».

Comment: Возможно, я не так выразилась, поэтому привожу выдержки их словаря: У Шанского: ВАРЯГ  Др.-рус. заимств. (до изменения носового e < in в ’а) из др.-сканд. яз., где váringr — суф. производное от vár «обет, присяга» со значением «союзник, товарищ по клятве, воин, давший присягу». Далее развитие значения могло идти следующим образом: «(воин, давший клятву) > защитник > наемник (для защиты) > скандинав». Значение «посторонний, чужой» является новым и возникло из значения «норманн» < «наемник».

Comment: У Шанского: ПРЕДВАРИТЬ Др.-рус. преф. производное от варити «предварять, предупреждать» < «защищать». См. варяг, варежка.

Comment: @Sharon странно; может, имелось в виду, что просто нужно ознакомиться с этими статьями, чтобы иметь полную картину... Но объединять _варити_ и _варяг_ по меньшей мере странно.

Comment: Может быть, надо анализировать значение корня var в глаголе "варити", а такого анализа нет.

Comment: @Sharon с чего вы это взяли? Праслав. корень сравнивают, напр., с латышским vert, veŗu ‘бежать’.

Comment: Я просто предполагаю. Хорошо бы определить и.- е. корень, так обычно делается в словаре Черных.

Comment: @Sharon шутка в том, что его может и не быть ))

Comment: Да, Вы правы, этимология вещь не простая.

Answer (score 0):

Есть слово - преддверие, означающее "предшествие", "канун", "пороог". Примеры: преддверие праздника, преддверие  избы.
По смыслу слова предварительный и преддверие схожи. Схожи они и по звучанию, за исключением утраченной одной из "д" в прилагательном. А вот "проворный", действительно ближе к "вор".  На мой взгляд, ваши, Sharon, сомнения, обоснованы.

Comment: Я доверяю Шанскому, который выделяет в слове "предварительный" исторический корень ВАР. Но я сомневаюсь, что слово "проворный" образовано от слова вор. У Даля проворный - это изворотливый,  от глагола "вертеться". Ну и по поводу "варяга" тоже есть сомнения в происхождении этого слова.

Comment: Смотрите, как интересно получается у того же Шанского: двор происходит от дверь и означает дословно - "то, что находится за воротами(обратите внимание и на это слово)".  Придворный - при дворе. Почему бы и слову предварительный не прийти с этой линии...

Comment: Это не только мнение Шанского, в других словарях дается такое же объяснение. В 11-12 вв. в древнерусском языке существовал глагол "варити", и это, вероятно, подтверждается письменными источниками.

Answer (score 0):

ПредДверие, перед дверью, перед тем как, что то открыть.
Хотя здесь же можно много расписывать от чего пошло само слово "дверь", "отвалятся ворота".
Закрывать, накрывать, крыть... складывается ощущение, что предки всë же сначала научились готовить, варить, томить еду, а уж потом закрываться, Обороняться.